# Looping through set

Tags: java, loops, set

I create two classes. The first one (call it Class1) has one private attribute: price. The second one (call it Class2) needs to have a set of objects of Class1:

My code:

```
private HashSet set = new HashSet<Class1>();
```

The goal is to create a method in the Class2, which takes an int as an argument and goes through objects to check until it finds one, which has a price equal to a given as an argument number. It needs to return the object. For example, I want to find an object with a price of 500, so I call the function check(500) and it returns exactly that object, which has price of 500. How can I do it?

---

My code:

```
  public Class1 check(int p)
    { 
     Class1 c = new Class1(p);
     Iterator it = set.iterator();
     while(it.hasNext())
     {
     // HERE IS THE HELP NEEDED. Using an array it  
     // would be sth like if(element[i].price == p)
     // but I need to use set
      if()
      {}
    it.next();


    }
```

Comment: No need to loop (directly) if you simply use a Stream that you can get from the HashSet. But for better more complete answers, please create and post your [mcve] program -- please read the link.

Comment: take a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html it is an enhanced for loop

Comment: [Iterate through elements of HashSet](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/IteratethroughelementsofHashSet.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so - however you will need access to the `price` to be able to compare it. If price itself is private, there should be a getter for it, which I assume in my solution.

```
public Class1 check(int p) {
    for (Class1 c : set) {
        if (c.getPrice() == p) return c;
    }
    return null; // none found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class `Class1`, define a getter method

```
int getPrice() { return price; }
```

Use it in your class `Class2`

```
Class1 curObj = it.next(); 
if (curObj.getPrice() == p) {
    your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a getter of the price attribute in class1, then the check method can be as follows:

```
public Class1 check(int p) 
{
  for (Class1 c1 : set) 
  {
    if (c1.getPrice() == p) 
    return c1;
  } 
  return null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
public Class1 check(int p) {
    Iterator<Class1> it = set.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Class1 next = it.next();
        if (next.getPrice() == p) {
            return next;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I assumed your class Class1 has a `getPrice` method that returns the price, it is ofcourse impossible to compare the price that we need to find to the price of an object if there is no way to access the field.

Answer (score 0):

Your generic type declaration is incorrect and thus you have a [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html); and you should prefer the `Set` interface. Something like

```
private Set<Class1> set = new HashSet<>();
```

And you can use an enhanced [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) to iterate your `set` items and find a matching `price` with something like

```
public Class1 check(int p) {
    for (Class1 item : set) {
        if (item.getPrice() == p) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have private variables, expose them through getter function.
Setters and getters will always help you whenever you will write code with some frameworks like Spring, Hibernate, etc.

```
public class class2 {

    private HashSet set = new HashSet<Class1>();

    public Class1 check(int price) {
        Iterator<Class1> iterator = set.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Class1 next = iterator.next();
            if(next.getPrice() == price)
                return next;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class Class1 {
    private int price;

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can it iterate the set and in every iteration compare the object against the price parameter, if found return the object, if not return null

## Example

```
public Class1 check(int p)
    { 
     
     for(Class c : set){
         if(c.getPrice ()==p){
              return c;
         }
     }
     return null;
    }
```